# Почему регулярное выражение удаляет кириллицу?

Tags: java, кодировка, intellij-idea

Разбиваю string на массив char'ов и пытаюсь вывести, но ничего не выводит. С помощью тестирования понял, что в данном случае выражение `replaceAll("\\W","")` удаляет все кириллические буквы, не считая их за буквы. Как я понимаю, проблема скорее всего в кодировке, как это исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что, если открыть [документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum), можно увидеть, что `\W` обратно `\w`, а `\w` это `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам нашел ответ. Нужно `replaceAll("\\W","")` заменить на `replaceAll("(?U)\\W","")`